# No signing identity found matching 'iPhone Distribution: XXXXXXXX'

Tags: ios, gradle, javafx, certificate, ipa

When I launch the task "createIpa" i have this error:

> No signing identity found matching 'iPhone Distribution: XXXXXXXX'

After I downloaded the certificate in my keychain Access from Apple Developer I see the certificate in the list but the key is not inclueded, what is the reason?

Comment: Are you providing `iosSignIdentity` and `iosProvisioningProfile` in your build.gradle file? Did you download the provisioning profile from Xcode->Preferences->Accounts?

Comment: yes I included:                                                                                    iosSignIdentity = 'iPhone Distribution: *******'
 iosProvisioningProfile = '*********'  in build.grade and also downloaded from xcode the provision profile

Comment: Run `security find-identity -v -p codesigning` on a terminal, you will find out your valid signing identity (if any).

Comment: No there isn't the certificate but I have it on my keychain! So it's not valid? I also tried to regenerate the certificate but it doesn't work anyway.

Comment: Make sure you go to `Xcode->Preferences->Accounts`, and add your account if it is not there yet. Then you should see your configuration, and you can also download the provisioning profiles.

Comment: yes all are downloaded from Xcode->Preferences->Accounts, but I think there is a problem with distribution certificate (it doesn't contain the key when I exploring it in the list) in the KeyChian Accesss